# Finding a contour of constant density in a joint distribution

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I would appreciate any help to find the solution for the following problem. In short the problem is explained below:

What I need: I need to find a contour of constant density in joint distribution of d random variables. The distribution may or may not be Gaussian. If the distribution is not Gaussian, this counter may no longer be an ellipsoid (I am not sure about it).

What I have:

- **Option** $1$: I have $N$ numbers of $d$-dimensional points from a joint distribution (only these points are available, we do not access the closed form of distribution but $N$ can be large enough). I need to find ellipsoidal (or whatever is called instead of ellipsoid) uncertainty sets which covers $X$ % of these points. This should represent a contour of constant density in their joint distribution.
- **Option** $2$: The joint distribution (non Gaussian) of d random variables is available. The question is how to find a contour of constant density in this joint distribution. I know the formulation for the Gaussian distribution based on chi-square distribution.